# Nodejs OAuth Yelp API issues - signature invalid

Tags: node.js, oauth, yelp

I have tried searching and using multiple oauth modules, but I cannot get this to work.  This has gotten me the closest (code copied from https://arian.io/how-to-use-yelps-api-with-node/)

```
var yelp_search = function(input_parameters, call_back) {

    var httpRequest = "GET";
    var fileName = "./secret-config.json";
    var config = require(fileName);

    var url = 'http://api.yelp.com/v2/search';
    console.log(config.ConsumerKey);
    var search_parameters = {
        callback : "cb",
        location: "Sunnyvale, CA"
    }

    var oauth_parameters = {
        oauth_consumer_key : config.ConsumerKey,
        oauth_token : config.Token,
        oauth_nonce : n(),
        oauth_timestamp : n().toString().substr(0,10),
        oauth_signature_method : 'HMAC-SHA1',
        oauth_version : '1.0',
    };

    var parameters = _.assign(search_parameters, input_parameters, oauth_parameters);

    var consumerSecret = config.consumerSecret;
    var tokenSecret = config.tokenSecret;

    var signature = oauthSignature.generate(httpRequest, url, parameters, consumerSecret, tokenSecret,  { encodeSignature: false});
    parameters.oauth_signature = signature;
    var parameterURL = qs.stringify(parameters);

    var apiURL = url+'?'+parameterURL;

    console.log(apiURL);

    request(apiURL, function(error, response, body){
        return callback(error, response, body);
    });

};
```

However, I get this error: "error": {"text": "Signature was invalid", "id": "INVALID_SIGNATURE", "description": "Invalid signature. Expected signature base string:

I don't know what I am doing wrong!  Everything seems fine, but I cannot see what I am doing wrong...

Comment: error in your url. request url must be alphabet order.

Comment: hey OP did you fix this in the end?